# Combine two JSON Array of Objects Coming from Different Http Service in Angular 8

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

I am developing a new angular 8 project where in my component, I get json data from 2 different services.
the data is array of objects. I want to join the objects in the array and post it back to the database.

here is the code

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
name = 'Angular';


// data comes from Persons Service
person = [
{name: "john", id: 1, joined: "2018"},
{name: "sarah", id: 2, joined: "2019"}
]

// data comes from salary Service
salary = [
{name: "john", id: 1, salary: 3000},
{name: "sarah", id: 2, salary: 5000}
]


personWithSalary;


ngOnInit(){

}


}
```

How can I combine this data together and map the salaries to correct person so it goes into a new array like this:

```
personWithSalary = [
    {name: "john", id: 1, joined: "2018", salary: 3000},
    {name: "sarah", id: 2, joined: "2019", salary: 5000}
]
```

Comment: however, your `salary` already has the desired data

Comment: It has the desired data but the first array will have more properties than the second array, I have just made up this data for guidance.

Comment: I have edited the question so it can make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection to have `O(1)` while mapping `person` array:

```
const uniqueSalaries = new Map(salary.map(s => [s.id, s]));
const result = person.map(({id, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...uniqueSalaries.get(id)}));
```

An example:

```js
let person = [
    {name: "john", id: 1, joined: "2018"},
    {name: "sarah", id: 2, joined: "2019"}
]    
let  salary = [
    {name: "john", id: 1, salary: 3000},
    {name: "sarah", id: 2, salary: 5000}
];    

const uniqueSalaries = new Map(salary.map(s => [s.id, s]));
const result = person.map(({id, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...uniqueSalaries.get(id)}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Chris I am glad that it helped to you:)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` and the spread operator to merge your arrays:

```
const personWithSalary = this.person.reduce((result,person) => {
      const salary = this.salaries.find(sal => sal.id === person.id);
      if(salary){
        result.push({...person,...salary});
      }
      return result;
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    personWithSalary = person.map(p => {
        p['salary'] = salary.find(s =>s.name === p.name && s.id === p.id).salary;
        return p;
    })
```